# Datasource Explorer is missing in Eclipse Kepler

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I have recently downloaded Eclipse Kepler. In this Kepler version, The DataSource Explorer is missing. DataSource Explorer can be used to connect to various databases. The Database Development perspective is missing in Kepler version.Do I need to install any separate plugin for that? If so, which plugin?

Answer (score 11):

The data source explorer is part of Eclipse DTP (Data Tools Platform).

You can install it from 'Help > Install New Software'. Choose the main Kepler repository in 'work with' and look in the Database Development section.

Comment: Thanks for the response.I could not see "Database Tools " section, but I could see "Database Development". Do you actually mean that?

Comment: I've just ran into the same problem today. In my STS Data Source Explorer was missing. Do what @greg-449 said - go to Help > Install New Software and check Database Development. Once you restart STS - Data Source Explorer will be under Show View > Other > Data Management.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Spring Tool Suite (based on eclipse) I was able to get the Data Source Explorer by going to **Help > Eclipse Marketplace** and then typing Database tool suite. The option Eclipse DTP comes up and then you can install it and restart.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Eclipse DataTools Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/datatools).

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse (Mars) Goto Help > Install New Software'. Choose the main Mars - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars repository in 'work with' and look in the *Database Development*. select this and sub directories and install.